# Python multiprocess - PicklingError: Cant pickle

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

The following class `Downloader` is supposed to query a SQL database multiple times and store the results in a list of `pandas.DataFrame` objects.

I would like to use `multiprocessing` to speed up the retrieval, however I get the error

```
    line 53, in run_queries
    dfs_queries = p.map(run_query, queries)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537809/python-multiprocessing-and-database-access-with-pyodbc-is-not-safe) question which suggests that the pyodbc connection and cursor objects can not be pickled. Is there a way to still use the `pool.map(f, arglist)` from `multiprocessing` when `f` is reliant on a sql connection?

```
import pyodbc
from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool
import pandas as pd

class Downloader(object):

    def _connect(self, path_db_config):
        # ... Loads a config file from which it gets dsn, user and password ... #

        con_string = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;' % (dsn, user, password)
        return pyodbc.connect(con_string)

    def run_queries(self):
        queries = [# List of sql queries #]
        p = ThreadPool(len(queries))

        def run_query(query):
            cnxn = self._connect(PATH_DB_CONFIG)
            df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
            return df

        return p.map(run_query, queries)
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Whether or not there is a way around the cursor issue I'm not sure but  you are also trying to use multiprocessing - which relies on pickling - on a nested function; [you cannot do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019961/python-pickling-nested-functions)

Comment: but the it should only pickle `run_query` no? and there is no nested method in there

Comment: `run_query` _is_ nested though.

Comment: ok will keep that in mind. I think I need to extend `Process` and put both the sql connection and query functionality into the `run()` method. Then I loop through the queries, instantiating a process for each query and putting the result into a `multiprocessing.Queue` where I can retrieve it from later

Comment: You may want to look into something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470403/pickling-class-method). Your proposed approach doesn't seem IIUC to address the issue. Basically, the function you want to pass to multiprocessing needs to be accessible in the module namespace.